# Variables not available in closure

Tags: javascript, jquery, closures

I'm having trouble assigning some variables as within a closure scope of a javascript class/jQuery plugin.

When I move into Article.initObj() as in the constructor of the Article class, I can't see either `domElement` or `settings` in my closure scope, but I **can** see `me` and `testVar`. This is confusing me quite a lot. Can anyone shed some light on what be might going on here?

**EDIT**: I've tried this in both firefox and chrome.

Here's my HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="ArticleNav.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                // Init our Viomedia article graph
                var articleList = $("#entityList").children().ArticleNav();             
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="leftPanel" class="vpanel">
            <div id="#search">
                <label for="searchField">Search </label>
                <input style="float: right;" name="searchField" id="searchField"/>
            </div>
            <div id="tree">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="rightPanel" class="vpanel">
            <div id="entityList" >
                <div class="article program" id="1">
                    <div class="title">The Simpsons</div>
                    <div class="article playlist" id="2">
                        <div class="title">Classic Episodes</div>
                        <div class="article episode" id="6">
                            <div class="title">Homer the Heretic</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="article season" id="3">
                        <div class="title">Season 4</div>
                        <div class="article episode" id="4">
                            <div class="title">Kamp Krusty</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="article episode" id="5">
                            <div class="title">A Streetcar Named Marge</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="article episode" id="6">
                            <div class="title">Homer the Heretic</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="article episode" id="7">
                            <div class="title">Lisa the Beauty Queen</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="artist article" id="7">
                    <div class="title">Electric Light Orchestra</div>
                    <div class="article album" id="8">
                        <div class="title">The Essential Electric Light Orchestra</div>
                        <div class="article album" id="9">
                            <div class="title">Disc 1</div>
                            <div class="article track" id="10">
                                <div class="title">So Serious</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="article album" id="11">
                            <div class="title">Disc 2</div>
                            <div class="article track" id="12">
                                <div class="title">Last Train to London</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="program article" id="13">
                    <div class="title">Archer</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here's my jQuery plugin:

```
(function($){

    var Article = function (element, options)
    {
        var me = this;
        var testVar = "I can read this";
        var domElement = $(element);

        var settings = $.extend({}, options || {});

        this.initObj = function()
        {
            me.test();
        };

        this.test = function()
        {
            console.log(testVar);
        };

        this.initObj();
    };

    var construct = function(element) {
        var element = $(element);
        // If this element already has this plugin attached to it.
        if(element.data('Article')) {
            return;
        }

        var ArticlePlugin = new Article(element);
        element.data('Article', ArticlePlugin);
    };

    $.fn.ArticleNav = function(func) {

        return this.each(function()
        {
            switch (func) {
                default:
                    construct(this);
                    break;
            }
        });
    };

}( jQuery ));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`domElement` is available from `.initObj()` from the parent closure scope.  Did you actually try to use it or did you just not see it in the debugger?

If you are stepping through `initObj()` in the debugger, you won't see `domElement` as a local variable in the debugger because it is in a higher scope, but if you do an explicit watch on it, you will be able to see it.  If you write code in `initObj()` that references it, it will work.

Same for `settings`.

Comment: Sigh. Yep, this is the second time my debugger has lied to me. Feel pretty stupid now. Thanks!